# Divide map area into overlapping circles of given radius

Tags: java, language-agnostic, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I'm trying to divide an area of a map of a given radius from given coordinates into smaller overlapping maps of another given radius, making sure the entire original map is covered by the smaller maps while minimizing overlap.

I need to find the center latitude/longitude of all smaller maps that cover the entire original area. The total area of the smaller maps may expand a little to make sure the entire surface is covered.

I tried various approaches until I realized this is a complex problem for which my math seems to be inadequate.

#### Code example

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ====  Parameters  =====
        /* These are just example values; Should work with any sensible input */
        LatLng outerAreaCenter = new LatLng(40.689259, -74.044538);
        double outerAreaRadiusInMeters = 1000;
        double divisionsRadiusInMeters = 125;

        // ====  Divide area  =====
        List<LatLng> divisionCenters;
        divisionCenters = divideArea(outerAreaCenter, outerAreaRadiusInMeters, divisionsRadiusInMeters);

        // ====  Draw large area  =====
        drawCircleOnMap(outerAreaCenter, outerAreaRadiusInMeters);

        // ====  Draw division circles within large area  =====
        /* These circles should cover the entire surface of the outer area, and
         * may extend a little bit outside of the outer circle if needed */
        for (LatLng divisionCenter : divisionCenters) {

            drawCircleOnMap(divisionCenter, divisionsRadiusInMeters);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Divides a large area into divisions/smaller areas that, together, cover the entire surface of the large area with minimal overlap.
     *
     * @param outerAreaCenter the center coordinates of the area that needs to be divided
     * @param outerAreaRadiusInMeter the radius of the area that needs to be divided
     * @param divisionsRadiusInMeter the maximum radius of each division/smaller area
     *
     * @return a list of center coordinates for each of the smaller areas that, which can be used with {@param divisionsRadiusInMeter} to make new areas that together cover the entire large area surface
     */
    private static List<LatLng> divideArea(LatLng outerAreaCenter, double outerAreaRadiusInMeter, double divisionsRadiusInMeter) {

        // ====  Check preconditions  =====
        if (divisionsRadiusInMeter > outerAreaRadiusInMeter) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divisions radius cannot be larger than radius of outer area."); }

        // ====  Calculate center lat/lng for each division  =====
        /* This is what my question is about. */
    }

    private static void drawCircleOnMap(LatLng circleCenter, double radiusInMeters) {

        /* Some code to draw this circle on a map (not relevant to the question) */

        // To visualize points, add a new layer on https://mapmakerapp.com by pasting the console output
        System.out.println(circleCenter.latitude + "," + circleCenter.longitude + ",,#FF0000");

    }

    private static class LatLng {

        private final double latitude;
        private final double longitude;

        private LatLng(double latitude, double longitude) {

            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Question

How do I calculate the center latitude/longitude of each division area, making sure the entire outer area is covered with minimum overlap? I'm basically looking for the method body of `divideArea(LatLng outerAreaCenter, double outerAreaRadiusInMeter, double divisionsRadiusInMeter)` in the code example above.

#### Note

It might be that for the overlap to be minimal, the radius of the division areas should also be an output. If that's the case then the `divisionsRadiusInMeters` parameter should be `divisionsMaxRadiusInMeters`.

### Edit

Following Avi's suggestion I added a code example and clarified the question.

Comment: 125 m. radius or diameter? It's not clear what you are asking here. Please provide a [reprex] so that we can better understand what you are trying to do. Furthermore, it would be very helpful if you provided a few example inputs/outputs.

Comment: You're right, I've written some code that I added to my question. The outputs are missing because my math isn't adequate to figure out what the center coordinates of the output should be. But the code will hopefully make clear what I mean.

Comment: The 125m example is radius.I used radius since that's what seems to be common in mapping tools, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I realize that it might be that the radius of the division areas should also be an output, if the overlap should be minimal. If that's the case then `divisionsRadiusInMeters` should be `divisionsMaxRadiusInMeters`.

Comment: It may be simpler to keep it as a fixed radius. After all, the maximum possible area could be covered by keeping the radius to the maximum.

Comment: I'm all for simple, as long as I can control the (maximum or fixed) size of the division areas.

Comment: I couldn't do the math either :( However, I did find [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_covering_problem), which covers the exact same problem. All you have to do is divide your input disc radius by itself (becoming the unit disc), and the smaller disc radius by the bigger one (becoming `r(n)`). Once you have the solution, you multiply both back to their original sizes/placements. It's probably not a solved problem, though, so you're probably better off using an approximation (e.g. genetic algorithm) or defaulting to some  fixed approximation that you have proven to work.

Comment: Good find :) Looks like it’s a harder puzzle than I thought, but I’ll have a go at it tomorrow. Thanks for trying! You mentioned original placements, but only the outer circle has a known placement. Do you have a rough idea of how to approach placement of the inner circles?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198150/discussion-between-avi-and-rolf-w).

Comment: ‘All you have to do is divide your inout disc radius by itself’. Would ‘t the result of that always be 1 though? In the example of 1000m, 1000/1000=1.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have a unit circle, then cover it with smaller circles. Once you cover the unit circle perfectly, you can scale it up to any number (especially back to the original) with simple multiplication of all dimensions of all points. You can check chat for the additional picture that I found on hexagonal lattice grids of circles.